# How to get JSON value by using iteration in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, iteration

I have a project that I'm working on using `Node.js` and I'm having trouble when I try to iterate through object properties. I'm new to this kind of iteration. I'm used to write `data.value` to access a value, but I can't access a value like that, I need to access the value by using iteration in JavaScript.

I have this `JSON` data

```
var data = {
  "internal": {
      "services": {
         "core": "OK",
         "comments": "NOK",
         "id": "OK"
     }
  }
}
```

I need to get the `OK` or `NOK` values using JavaScript iteration.

I tried this

```
for (var key of Object.values(data)) {
     if (key === 'NOK') {
         axios.post(slackWebhookURL, {
             text: `Problems found in ${key}`
         })
     } else axios.post(slackWebhookURL, {
         text: 'Everything is working properly.'
     })
}
```

I've tried with `Object.keys()`, `Object.entries()`, `Object.getOwnPropertyName()` but none of them worked, none of them returned `OK` or `NOK`.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: You need `Object.keys(data.internal.services)` if you're wanting to iterate over that set of properties.

Comment: I've seen the same answer below, I'll try this. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `entries` as follow:

```
for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(data.internal.services)) {...}
```

```js
var data = {
  "internal": {
      "services": {
         "core": "OK",
         "comments": "NOK",
         "id": "OK"
     }
  }
}

for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(data.internal.services)) {
     if (value === 'NOK') {
         console.log(`Problems found in '${key}'`);             
     } else {
        console.log(`Everything is working properly in  '${key}'`);
     }
}
```

Comment: Aaa I think I get it now, how was I so blind? Thank you, I'll try this!

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the correct property of your object literal. Also, simply use `some()`

```js
var data = {
  "internal": {
    "services": {
      "core": "OK",
      "comments": "NOK",
      "id": "OK"
    }
  }
};

if (Object.values(data.internal.services).some(e => e === 'NOK')) {
  axios.post(slackWebhookURL, {
    text: `Problems found in ${key}`
  });
} else {
   axios.post(slackWebhookURL, {
    text: 'Everything is working properly.'
  });
}
```

Comment: I believe it works since you have a large amount of reputation and I checked your profile and I saw that you have the highest score in JavaScript, so I'll upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You use the 'dot' syntax to access the inner properties

```
console.log('core: ' + data.internal.services.core);
console.log('comments: ' + data.internal.services.comments);
console.log('id: ' + data.internal.services.id);
```

To iterate you need to loop through the object that contains the properties whose values you want to observe, in this case `data.internal.services`.

```js
var data = {
  "internal": {
      "services": {
         "core": "OK",
         "comments": "NOK",
         "id": "OK"
     }
  }
}

for (var propName in data.internal.services) {
     if (data.internal.services[propName] === 'NOK') {
         console.log(propName + ': NOK')
     } else {
         console.log(propName + ': OK')
     }
}
```

Comment: The first part of the answer is unnecessary but I do believe that the other part of the answer is correct.